# How can I make a custom button in Xcode using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode6

I'm trying to make custom buttons in Xcode 6 using swift, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I make a class in my viewController.swift file using assistant editor and then apply that class to the buttons in question?

Comment: Do you want to make it programmatically or in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a hello world example.

```
class myViewcontroller: UIViewController{
var helloLabel : UILabel!
var abutton   :UIButton!

func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
    if (helloLabel.text == "tap it again please good sir"){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    helloLabel.text = "tap it again please good sir"

}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
        }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    helloLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 50))
    helloLabel.text = "hello world"
    helloLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    abutton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 50))
    abutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    abutton.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    abutton.addTarget(self, action: "viewTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(abutton)

    self.view .addSubview(helloLabel)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
 }
```